# Change .m2 directory for each build

Tags: java, maven

We build artifacts for our Alpha,BETA and Stage environments from same machine. Each environment run on different release version and we cannot reuse .m2, because Alpha build populates future release artifacts in m2 and that will be incorrect for BETA and Stage. So every time we build, we delete old M2 directory and repopulate it with environment specific code base. Hope this explains little better

Comment: You should explain your use case more detailed

Comment: "multiple versions of code" - If there are multiple versions, why the need to delete .m2 each time? It seems like you are doing something very wrong here.

Comment: This doesn't sound right at all. Why are you deleting `.m2` each time? What do you mean by "repopulating it with new code base"?

Comment: We build artifacts for our Alpha,BETA and Stage environments from same machine. Each environment run on different release version and we cannot reuse .m2, because Alpha build populates future release artifacts in m2 and that will be incorrect for BETA and Stage. So every time we build, we delete old M2 directory and repopulate it with environment specific code base. Hope this explains little better....

Comment: Follow this [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-a-custom-maven-settings-xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the settings file with `-s` and the private repo with `-Dmaven.repo.local`. Between these two you pretty much get the same as a different `.m2`.

`mvn -s codebase-specific-maven-settings.xml -Dmaven.repo.local=/path/to/codebase-specific-repo`